# How could I insert a smaller box into a form box via javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

This is what I have:

[image]

This is what I'm going for:

[image]

I tried using html-tables but I just can't get the proportions right and end up with something like this:

[image]

So I feel that I need to insert the box into the existing form box using JS. Appreciate any pointers to how I could go about achieving this.

Comment: I think you'd be better off making two elements. If you post your html and css we can help with the formatting.

Comment: You can't put another element "within" a text box (be it an `input` or `textarea` tag). Do it with layout, flexbox or three elements (container, left and right), with the one on the right being your element. You don't need javascript to do this either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code will add a prefix after 1 second

```js
function addPrefix() {
  var newNode = document.createElement("div");
  var newContent = document.createTextNode("+1"); 
  newNode.appendChild(newContent);
  newNode.style.cssText = "border: 1px solid blue; box-sizing: border-box;height: 30px; line-height: 30px; float: left"

  var targetDiv = document.getElementById("phone");
  var parentDiv = targetDiv.parentNode;

  parentDiv.insertBefore(newNode, targetDiv);
}

setTimeout(addPrefix, 1000);
```

```css
#phone{
  height: 30px; 
  box-sizing: border-box;
 }
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
<input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Mobile or email" />
</form>
```

Comment: thanks very very much! How would I go about doing this if the ```+1``` isn't a textbox but a <select> dropdown menu instead? Is there a document.createSelectNode() or something similar?